# Trying to read from NetworkStream crashes program, no exception or error

Tags: c#, sockets, stream

I'm trying to read data from a socket, however whenever I try to read the entire stream my program hangs. With no error or exception.

I can manually read say 4 bytes and it will work, however I no longer know the exact size of the data the server will send, therefore I wish to read the entire stream. What am I doing wrong?

It hangs when calling ReadToEnd().

```
Stream input = socket.GetStream();

byte[] request = new byte[5];

input.Write(request, 0, 5); //send request

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);

if (input.CanRead == true)
{
    string test = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?  You are reading a stream, which can literally be infinitely long.  If your program is single threaded, there's a good chance you have not completed ReadToEnd().

Comment: Well I should say it hangs, it doesn't move past that line. However if I read say 5 bytes instead of 4 it also hangs in the same manner.

Comment: From the streamreader help page:  

ReadToEnd assumes that the stream knows when it has reached an end. For interactive protocols in which the server sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection, ReadToEnd might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end, and should be avoided.

How do you know when the server has finished sending you data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code canot know how long the stream is, it's possibly not ended so its going to continue to block until it has. Below is an example server and client (**in no way is this a robust implementation**) but if you consider the following code you should see how to send a request and receive a response:

```
    public class Server
    {
        private readonly Thread _listenThread;
        private readonly TcpListener _tcpListener;

        public Server()
        {
            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
            _listenThread = new Thread(Listen);
            _listenThread.Start();
        }

        private void Listen()
        {
            var tcpListener = _tcpListener;

            if (tcpListener != null)
            {
                tcpListener.Start();
            }

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Connection Accepted");
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(DoWork);
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }

        private void DoWork(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = client as TcpClient;

            if (tcpClient == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("client", "Must pass client in");
            }

            using (NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] message = new byte[1024];

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Waiting for message");
                    int bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 1024);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string received = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);

                    Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("Read {0}", received));
                    if (received.Equals("Hello Server !"))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Client!");
                        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        clientStream.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You would need a client that did something like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            using (TcpClient clientSock = new TcpClient(IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(), 3000))
            {
                using (Stream clientStream = clientSock.GetStream())
                {
                    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    byte[] helloMessage = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server !");

                    clientStream.Write(helloMessage, 0, helloMessage.Length);
                    clientStream.Flush();

                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(clientStream))
                    {
                        while(true)
                        {
                            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                            streamReader.Read(buffer,0, 1024);

                            Console.Out.WriteLine(new string(buffer));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do something here

            throw;
        }
    }
```